# Custom Ember Api Endpoint

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to figure out how to get data from a custom api. I am using Ember 1.8.1, Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.12 and Ember CLI

In my router i have the following resource
`this.resource("communities", {path: '/communities/:community-id/follow-ups'}, function() {});`

I have my model defined for the correct response. In my communities router I am trying to get the data from the api like so 
`this.store.find('community', params['community-id']);`

The problem I am having is that I am trying to retrive data from the api endpoint 
`/communities/{community-id}/follow-ups`
But the app is trying to grab the data from 
`/communities/{community-id}`

How do I define the custom resource route to pull from the `follow-ups`

Comment: If either of these answers satisfies your question, can you accept it? ;)

Answer (score 1):

The router path isn't going to change where the API makes the call to, that just helps Ember change the browser path. 
You might want to consider using an adapter if you really need it to hit `.../follow-ups`.

You'd want to make a `CommunitiesAdapter` I think. `ember g adapter communities`, or `community`, not sure offhand.

And I think the function on it you're looking for is `pathForType`.

Check it out at http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/models/customizing-adapters/

Comment: Command is `ember g adapter community`.  Ember.String.dasherize is a useful function for this issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom adapter for your model in particular but deep nesting on routes can be tricky in Ember and not worth the time if you are in a rush.

Try setting the model of the route directly with a get json

```
App.NAMERoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model : function(params){
       return Ember.$.getJSON(window.apiHost+'/communities/'+params.group_id+'/follow-ups');
   }
});
```

Sometimes simple solutions is what you need